# How to list all of the attributes in a terraform_remote_state datasource?

Tags: terraform

I've been trying to debug an issue related to a terraform_remote_state datasource.

Goal: Show all of the attributes in `data terraform_remote_state my_remote_state`

Attempt: `terraform state show data.terraform_remote_state.my_remote_state`

Expected: show all attributes for the datasource

Result:

```
No instance found for the given address!

This command requires that the address references one specific instance.
To view the available instances, use "terraform state list". Please modify 
the address to reference a specific instance.
```

I ran `terraform state list` to view the list addresses, but the datasource address wasn't listed. If anyone can help me with this I would greatly appreciate it.

references:https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/state/show.html

Comment: `terraform state show` can only show data that's already recorded in the state. If you've only just added that `data` block to your configuration then you may need to run `terraform apply` to commit the result of that data source to the state before you can see it in `terraform state show`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commands `terraform state show` and `terraform state list` will show you the resources contained within the state for your **current** backend. Remote state is not state managed by your current backend.

If you have access to the definition for the other backend, simply change to that project/repo, initialise, make sure you're in the correct workspace, then use `terraform state show` and `terraform state list` there instead.